# Math in python - converting data files to matrices

Tags: python, list, io

Today, as I tried to put together a script in Octave, I thought, this may be easier in python.  Indeed the math operators of lists are a breeze, but loading in the file in the format is not as easy.  Then I thought, it probably is, I am just not familiar with the module to do it!

So, I have a typical data file with four columns of numbers. I would like to load each column into separate lists.  Is there a module I should use to make this easier?

Comment: Thanks!  Does anyone know about getting Numpy on OSX?  I chose py26-numpy from macports, but it seems to be downloading python 2.6, which I already had, so I may have screwed up with this approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is applicable to your problem, but you might try it with `numpy`, especially its `loadtxt` and `savetxt` functions. You should then use only `numpy` arrays and avoid Python lists as they are not apt for numerical computations.

Answer (score 2):

For fast calculations with matrices you should try [Numpy](https://numpy.org/), it has some functions to [load data from files](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.io.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with 2-dimensional data or enormously long lists, [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) is the way to go, but if you're not looking to do terribly advanced math, you can get by with regular Python.

```
>>> table = []
>>> a = "32 42 63 1123"
>>> table.append(a.split(" ")) # this would be some loop where you file.readline()...
>>> table.append(a.split(" "))
>>> table.append(a.split(" "))
>>> table.append(a.split(" "))
>>> table
[['32', '42', '63', '1123'], ['32', '42', '63', '1123'],
['32', '42', '63', '1123'], ['32', '42', '63', '1123']]
>>> zip(*table) # this "transposes" the list of lists
[('32', '32', '32', '32'), ('42', '42', '42', '42'), 
('63', '63', '63', '63'), ('1123', '1123', '1123', '1123')]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is certainly a useful approach to many other things I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get Numpy working is to download Enthought Python Distribution. This is especially true for Mac since installing numpy, scipy, ... from scratch will take you a lot of effort.

For loading and saving some files like:

```
# This is some comment
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

You do

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(input_filename, comment='#')
```

Comment: !!  I don't want to pay 200 bucks for something that comes free!  Is there no other way to do this?  Apparently numpy is already on my machine, but when I try to use it, I get all kinds of weird errors.

Comment: I guess you are not in academia and cannot take advantage of their free 32-bit for Mac. Can you create another question with the detailed errors you encounter when trying to use numpy on your machine?